# Making a forecast: Confidence/Prediction/Tolerance Interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, forecasting, prediction-interval, tolerance-interval

I understand the the difference between these three types of intervals but I will summarize briefly:

- Confidence Interval: an interval that will contain the **true mean** value say, 95%, of the time.
- Prediction Interval: an interval that will contain 95% of all response values for a single new observation.
- Tolerance Interval: an range that will contain a given proportion of the population 95% of the time.

My question is in regards as to which I would use when making a prediction. For the sake of a useful example, perhaps I am predicting the winner of an election. **Which interval would be most statistically correct and beneficial to use?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on what you want to use the forecast and the interval for.

For instance, I do forecasting for retail, and our prediction intervals (more precisely: high quantile forecasts) are used for replenishment. In such a use case, the relevant thing is, say, a 95% quantile forecast, because this will translate more-or-less into a specific service level, which will hopefully balance the costs of understock and overstock.

As an example, let's look at the `AirPassengers` dataset. Maybe we want to provide enough capacity to achieve a service level of 95%. We can do this by fitting a model and looking at a 90% prediction interval. This is comprised of the 5% and the 95% quantile forecasts. Below, the "Lo 90%" is the number such that we expect a 5% chance of observing fewer passengers, while the "Hi 90%" is the number such that we expect a 95% chance of observing fewer passengers - together, the two numbers bracket off a prediction interval that we expect a 90% chance of covering the next observation.

```
> library(forecast)
> (foo <- forecast(auto.arima(AirPassengers),h=1,level=0.90))
         Point Forecast   Lo 90    Hi 90
Jan 1961       446.7582 427.413 466.1034
> plot(foo)
```

[image: forecast with prediction interval]

So, to achieve 95% service level, we would plan for providing capacity for 466.1 (thousand) passengers. (I'm glossing over different possible definitions of the service level, which here don't really make a difference. Plus, in planning for a longer lead time, we would need to take remaining autocorrelation into account, and so forth.)

Most forecasters I work with are only interested in prediction intervals, because you can verify them to a certain extent, simply by observing the next realization. Confidence intervals can never be verified, and you will have to trust that you have a correctly specified model for the mathematics to work. (And I have never seen the tolerance interval used in forecasting.)

When you are predicting the winner of an election, a prediction interval does not really make sense, because this random variable is not numeric. Unless you are not predicting the *winner*, but, say, a candidate's *share of the vote*.

Comment: Thank you! Can you go into more detail explaining the quantile forecast? Maybe even using some R code as well (I saw you also use R).